# create_engine error: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python-3.x, string, sqlalchemy

I'm running a small python script with SQLalchemy.

I have the following error `not all arguments converted during string formatting` when trying to pass the db name as variable. I don't really understand why.

this is working:

`create_engine('mysql://'+user+':'+passwd+'@127.0.0.1:%s/my_db' % server.local_bind_port)`

This is not working:

```
var db_name = 'my_db'
create_engine('mysql://'+user+':'+passwd+'@127.0.0.1:%s/' + db_name % server.local_bind_port)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `db_name % server.local_bind_port` is evaluated first and db_name contains no format specifiers.

Comment: how do I specify the format?

Comment: `create_engine(f'mysql://{user}:{passwd}@127.0.0.1:{server.local_bind_port}/{db_name}')`

Comment: It's working. so this is just a formatting issue. what wrong exactly in my create engine statement?